# error: expected ';' before '__retval' : Error message when compiling

Tags: c, mingw

When I run the code, which nothing is wrong with, I keep receiving the error message that I am missing a semicolon somewhere. When I search other online sources, they indicate that the problem is with the header file (stdio.h). It was also recommended that I update MinGW, I did but the same problem still persists.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /*
     2.    
     Write a program that finds the smallest element in the sequence s1, s2, .... sn of n 
     distinct numbers. The input is the sequence, s, and the index, n, of the last term of the sequence. The output is the index of the smallest element in the sequence. 
     */
 
  int nunElements, s_index = 0; 
  printf("Enter the last index of the sequence: "); 
  scanf("%d", &nunElements); 
  int sequence[nunElements]; /*Array to store the sequence of distinct numbers. */ 
  printf("\nEnter the sequence of distinct numbers separate by space: "); 
  for (int i = 0; i < nunElements; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &sequence[i]); 
  }

  for (int j = 1; j < nunElements; j++)
  {
    if (sequence[j] < sequence[s_index])
      s_index = j; 
  }
  printf("The smallest index is: %d\n", s_index); 

  return 0; 
}
```

The complete error message is:

```
In file included from Talaash_Esmat_Problem2_HW1.c:1:
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h: In function 'scanf':
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h:305:2: error: expected ';' before '__retval'
305 | 3 __retval = __mingw_vfscanf( stdin, __format, __local_argv );
    | ^ ~~~~~~~~ | ;
```

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add details, instead of using the comments.

Comment: And what do lines 300-305 of that file actually look like? You possibly edited it by mistake.

Comment: Since the problem is reported in `<stdio.h>`, it seems that your compiler installation is corrupted (or, at least, that the file `<stdio.h>` is not compilable).  You mention "WinGW" — do you mean "MinGW"?

Comment: Here's the file at Github, for what it is worth: https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/stdio.h  You could diff it against your local file.

Comment: Since I do not know how to respond to each comment separately, I will just try to address all of the above comments here:  #paxdiablo: lines 300 - 305 do not exist in the file. The program is only 35 lines long. #Jonathan Leffler; That was actually my initial thought, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: He meant lines 300 to 305 of `stdio.h`, more specifically, `c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h`, not your program. You should compare that file against Lundin's link. Also, you should use the form @Hammer if you want to reply and notify somebody who has commented. From what I can tell so far, you should remove the`3 ` from line 305 of `stdio.h`.